# how to format jquery script to production?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

I have my json script that gets my categories and puts that into a nivo slider. Works well.

```
(function() {
    var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=gw-preview&format=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        if(data.items[i] != null){
            var current = data.items[i];
            var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
            $('ul.slides').append(post);
        }
    }
});
})();

(function() {
    var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=gw-news&format=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        if(data.items[i] != null){
            var current = data.items[i];
            var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
            $('ul.slides').append(post);
        }
    }
});
})();

(function() {
    var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=captaincy-analysis&format=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        if(data.items[i] != null){
            var current = data.items[i];
            var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
            $('ul.slides').append(post);
        }
    }
});
})();

(function() {
  var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=pundits-team&format=json&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    if(data.items[i] != null)
    {
        var current = data.items[i];
        var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
        $('ul.slides').append(post);
    }
}
  });
})();

(function() {
  var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=strategy&format=json&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    if(data.items[i] != null)
    {
        var current = data.items[i];
        var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
        $('ul.slides').append(post);
    }
}
  });
})();

(function() {
  var url = 'http://my url.com/blog/?category=new-signings&format=json&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {    
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    if(data.items[i] != null)
    {
        var current = data.items[i];
        var post =  '<li><a href="http://my url.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"></a></li>' ;
        $('ul.slides').append(post);
    }
}
  });
})();
```

How would i go along in making to more lightweight, do i just compile it so it minifies it? or is their parts I can better.
To me it looks a tad heavy, but without expert knowledge I dont really know the options

Comment: My favorite! http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/) are some tools that are good for minifying javascript.

1. [JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) is a conservative compressor, written several years ago by Douglas Crockford. It is considered safe (especially if you verify your code with JSLint first-- an excellent thing to do anyway) because it doesn't attempt to change any variable names.
2. [Dojo shrinksafe](http://dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe) is a very popular Java based JavaScript compressor that parses the JavaScript using the rhino library and crunches local variable names.
3. [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) (Version 3.1) by Dean Edwards, is also a very popular JavaScript compressor, that can go beyond regular compression and also add advanced on-the-fly decompression with a JavaScript runtime piece.
4. [the YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) (Version 2.4.2) is a newer compressor written by Julien Lecomte, that aims to combine the safety of JSMin with the higher compression levels acheived by Dojo Shrinksafe. Like Dojo shrinksafe, it is written in Java and based on the rhino library.
5. [Google closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)
6. [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/)

Comment: excellent thankyou. as you can sense, im a bit of a tool at JS atm. but im getting along ok. Again thankyou. Shame I cant vote up.

Comment: You are really close though!

Comment: If this answer helps you should accept. And then you should have gained enough rep to start upvoting :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, Forgot to accept the answers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is not compiled, however you can minify it. You can use closure compiler for this:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

However the amount of javascript you have there is not significant. As long as your Jquery library is already minified there won't be much difference. In either way it is seen as good practice to minify javascript :)

Comment: ohhhh saying that I did stumble across this a month or two back but I wanted proper advice before I done anything. Thankyou people

Answer (score 0):

One way is to minify it: http://www.jsmini.com/

This should help somewhat

Answer (score -2):

You could try [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) and convert it to CoffeeScript. Might be easier to rework it then. CoffeeScript is little more elegant than JavaScript.

Commence the downvoting...

Comment: Your advice to cleanup javascript is to have him convert it to another language, learn the new language, maybe reduce the footprint in said language, and then have it translated back to JS and hope it's better?  Really?

Comment: Just saying its easier to refactor CoffeeScript...My eyes bleed when I try to follow/refactor Javascript.